# How to use the selenium submission form data

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, web-scraping

execute this python code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time 

url = "http://125.221.35.78:8080/selfservice/" 
browser = webdriver.Firefox() 
browser.get(url)
time.sleep(5) 
browser.switch_to_frame("entry.jsp") 

username_element = browser.find_element_by_id('name_text') 
username_element.clear() 
username_element.send_keys('2016010387') 
time.sleep(2)

password_element = browser.find_element_by_id('password_text') 
password_element.clear() 
password_element.send_keys('123456')
time.sleep(2)
```

but this Python code is not work.because this two  tags contains javascript code.
such as:

```
<input tabindex="1" class="loginInputHK" type="text" value="username" id="name_text" onclick="this.className='loginInputHKClicked'" onfocus="this.className='loginInputHKClicked';" onblur="this.className='loginInputHK';" style="display: inline-block;">


<input tabindex="2" class="loginInputHK" type="text" value="password" id="password_text" onclick="this.className='loginInputHKClicked'" onfocus="hidePwdErrorImg()" onblur="this.className='loginInputHK';blurPwdDiv()" style="display: inline-block;">
```

How to execute this javascript code in selenium scrapy ?

Can everyone help me?
Thank you everybody!